# How to run X server without LXDE?

Tags: raspbian, xorg, lxde, framebuffer

I would like to run a "naked" X server (using a framebuffer for output) on the Pi.

However, `startx` will also start LXDE, just as `startlxde` and `startlxde-pi` do, and I cannot find a way to get around that. (LXDE does work fine with the framebuffer and all. It's just that I don't need+want a full DE for an embedded, single application system.)

What's the right way to launch an X server without LXDE on the Pi?

(Linux raspberrypi 4.1.13+ #826 PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:13:22 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux)

Answer (score 2):

xinit(1) is the script/command you are looking for!

Literal excerpt from the manpage:

> EXAMPLES
> Below are several examples of how command line arguments in xinit are used.
>
> - `xinit` This will start up a server named X and run the user's .xinitrc, if it exists, or else start an xterm.
> - `xinit -- /usr/bin/Xvnc  :1` This is how one could start a specific type of server on an alternate display.
> - `xinit -geometry =80x65+10+10 -fn 8x13 -j -fg white -bg navy` This will start up a server named X, and will append the given arguments to the default xterm command.  It will ignore .xinitrc.
> - `xinit -e widgets -- ./Xorg -l -c` This will use the command .Xorg -l -c to start the server and will append the arguments -e widgets to the default xterm command.
> - `xinit /usr/ucb/rsh fasthost cpupig -display ws:1 --  :1 -a 2 -t 5` This will start a server named X on display 1 with the arguments -a 2 -t 5.  It will then start a remote shell on the machine fasthost in which it will run the command cpupig, telling it to display back on the local workstation.
>
> Below is a sample .xinitrc that starts a clock, several terminals, and leaves the window manager running as the `last` application. Assuming that the window manager has been configured properly, the user then chooses the `Exit` menu item to shut down X.
>
> ```
>     xrdb -load $HOME/.Xresources
>     xsetroot -solid gray &
>     xclock -g 50x50-0+0 -bw 0 &
>     xload -g 50x50-50+0 -bw 0 &
>     xterm -g 80x24+0+0 &
>     xterm -g 80x24+0-0 &
>     twm
> ```
>
> Sites that want to create a common startup environment could simply create a default .xinitrc that references a site-wide startup file:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> . /etc/X11/xinit/site.xinitrc
> ```
>
> Another approach is to write a script that starts xinit with a specific shell script.  Such scripts are usually named x11, xstart, or startx and are a convenient way to provide a simple inter‐face for novice users:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> xinit /etc/X11/xinit/site.xinitrc -- /usr/bin/X -br
> ```

Comment: `startx` and `xinit` are really near synonyms.  However, if you read the man page it does explain *why* they might end up invoking lxde, and from there you can get how to have them run something else (or nothing but X).  Hint: It has to do with an initialization file with several potential names.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Reading up on `xinit`, which seems to require some more configuration, I got to the point of only running `X` (*capital* X!). That looks like what I wanted. If it turns out that it's not enough, I know that I should look into `xinit` now. Someone also recommended [Matchbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matchbox_%28window_manager%29) as a light-weight alternative to a DE. Might give that a try too.